# How to convert S3:pandas.core.frame.DataFrame in R reticulate dataframe?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

I´m using reticulate in R to read an pickle python file but when I try to convert the list object to R dataframe I see the following issue:

```
glimpse(d_first_month)

Rows: 2
Columns: 1
$ V1 <list> <<pandas.core.frame.DataFrame[3317 x 88]>>, <<pandas.core.frame.Da…

class(d_first_month$V1[[1]])

[1] "pandas.core.frame.DataFrame"        "pandas.core.generic.NDFrame"       
[3] "pandas.core.base.PandasObject"      "pandas.core.accessor.DirNamesMixin"
[5] "pandas.core.indexing.IndexingMixin" "pandas.core.arraylike.OpsMixin"    
[7] "python.builtin.object"
```

Comment: How can I convert this pandas dataframe for an normal R dataframe ?

Comment: Hi Rodrigo H. Ozon, please add your comment as an edit of your question (since it is the actual question). As far that I know it is not possible to share object in memory between R and Python. You will need to write your data on disk with e.g `d_first_month.to_csv('d_first_month.csv', index = False)` before reloading the file with R.